# Requests Failed ASP.NET Performance Counter shows constant high value

Tags: asp.net, azure, performancecounter, perfmon, iis-8.5

I have a ASP.NET website hosted on azure. For performance testing i am doing some load test, and reading the performance counter. The problem is the Requests Failed counter value, it is showing always high value and never goes to 0.

During the load test, due to some wrong settings all of the requests failed. And the Requests failed counter showed the proper high value. But then after fixing the issue, still the request failed counter is showing the high value.

I have checked the IIS logs, but i can't see any high number of 4xx or 5xx errors.

Is the Requests Failed counter shows value for past few hours ? And is there a way to reset it, or is there any counter to read **Requests Failed Per Sec**

Note: I am monitoring the ASP.NET Applications Requests Failed counter.
I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and the website is hosted on Azure.

Similar issue is with .NET CLR Exceptions (# of Exceps Thrown) -> this is also showing high value, but it has another counter called # Of Exceps Thrown /Sec which is showing 0 value.

Thanks,
Javed

Answer (score 1):

These counters maintain their values until an IIS restart occurs. When IIS is restarted they are reset to 0.